# Changing TSV call to CSV in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, csv

I would like to create a line graph in D3 working from a [Bostock example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569)

However he uses tsv and my file is csv. When I change "tsv" to "csv" in his example and convert the file to csv, the graph doesn't plot any points or draw the x axis labels.

I'm not sure I'm understanding what's going on here. Is there something else I should change rather than "tsv" to "csv"?

His example:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse,
    bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left,
    formatValue = d3.format(",.2f"),
    formatCurrency = function(d) { return "$" + formatValue(d); };

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Bostock calls the tsv file here. In my version I simply change to two references to tsv to "csv" and the graph does not plot points or draw the x axis labels.

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.date - b.date;
  });

  x.domain([data[0].date, data[data.length - 1].date]);
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

  var focus = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "focus")
      .style("display", "none");

  focus.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

  focus.append("text")
      .attr("x", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em");

  svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "overlay")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
      .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
      .on("mousemove", mousemove);

  function mousemove() {
    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
        d0 = data[i - 1],
        d1 = data[i],
        d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.close) + ")");
    focus.select("text").text(formatCurrency(d.close));
  }
});
```

His tsv can be found here[enter link description here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569)

Comment: Does your file have the same structure?

Comment: Your best bet is to throw in `console.log` or `debugger` statements to make sure that the data is what you think it is. You can also inspect the DOM to see whether you generated invalid SVG or no SVG at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the d3 function call for loading data. It should be d3.csv ("file.csv" , .. ) instead of d3.tsv("file.tsv", .. ). See the working example at this [plnkr link.](http://plnkr.co/edit/X4Nljyn6FmFnZOoNuEM6?p=preview)

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
```

Comment: Yes. I wrote in the original post that I changed tsv to csv on both references. I also created a csv file from the tsv file.

Comment: did you look at the plnkr link. The code is working there. Can you post what have you done so far?

Comment: I have the same thing, but it is not plotting. I think it has to do with parsing the dates.